# RedirectToAction when NullReferenceException of the Model is raised

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following controller method

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    try
    {
        Pacient pacientdp = new Pacient();
        if (pacientdp.PacientPrenume == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        var id = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        MedicalDBContext pacientContext = new MedicalDBContext();
        Pacient pacient = pacientContext.Pacients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PacientID == id);
        return View(pacient);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Home", "Index"));
    }
}
```

When navigating to Details View if I comment the if part from the controller method a NullReferenceException is raised. This happends sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't. This is the behaviour that I want.
So I added the if part so when the model property(PacientPrenume) is null to redirect to action, but this method redirects to action everytime, even if the model is not null.

With the above method, th if block is executed regardless of the pacientdp model(if is null or not)

How can I handle this exception only when the model???

Comment: If `pacientdp` is null, it's going to throw in the `if` condition, and the body of the `if` will never execute.

Comment: I don't understand, why the if body will never execut if pacientdp is null??

Comment: Because dereferencing `.PacientPrenume` will throw a nullreferenceexception, though that seems unlikely unless `new Pacient()` itself throws.  In any case, you never use `.PacientPrenume` again, so I'm wondering what the point is.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but why breakpoints that are set on if line are not triggered when navigating to Details view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, so the context model actualy sets the value for my model, so the pacientdp.PacientPrenume property was always null. Bellow is the working method

```
            public ActionResult Details()
                {
                try
                    {
                    MedicalDBContext pacientContext = new MedicalDBContext();
                    var id = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
                    if (pacientContext.Pacients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PacientID == id) == null)
                        {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }               
                        Pacient pacient = pacientContext.Pacients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PacientID == id);
                        return View(pacient);
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Home", "Index"));
                    }

                }
```